# Why can't I see logs in my lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I've been trying in vain to see logs for my lambda function. No matter what I see this:

[image: AWS Lambda Logs Error]

To be clear, the lambda function runs properly. I just can't see the logs at all.

I've recreated the function multiple times to make sure it wasn't me accidentally mucking with a setting that disabled logging.

My steps:

1. From the AWS Lambda function page, create a new function. I'm using nodejs 8.10, but it seems to fail even if I use a 6.x version.
2. Upload a zip file with my function (including the node_modules directory, package.json and package-lock.json as well) to S3 into `testbucket` with the filename `thumbnails.zip`.
3. Use this command to publish my lambda function from S3: `aws lambda update-function-code --function-name transcode-v2 --s3-bucket mytestbucket --s3-key thumbnails.zip`.
4. I can test my function with sample data and the test button.
5. I can also invoke it from the CLI and it seems to "work" (in that it runs)

I always see this message when I go to cloud logs: `There was an error loading Log Streams. Please try again by refreshing this page.` I've tried recreating the function twice and this does not fix it.

Anyone know what is wrong here? The function seems to work under test (meaning, I see logs inside the test logging dialog), and when I invoke from the command line. But, nothing ever gets into the cloud logging page except for that error.

I can see that invocations are being triggered from AWS.

[image: AWS Invocations]

Comment: Hmm have you checked for permissions issues? ie make sure your role has permission to write to CWL

Comment: Hmm, OK. I would have assumed the lambda function would get that already, but that makes sense that it would not. I'll check.

Comment: So, if I attach permissions to the user, I don't see anything for CWL. Is this permission named something else? I'm in the "roles" section of a user. Is that the correct place?

Comment: This to me (as a novice of AWS, tho...) does not look like a permissions issue. It looks like AWS has a configuration error somewhere, since the AWS console cannot load the logs, not that it says "A process cannot write to the logs..." (which I imagine would not be reported anyway). I've tried creating the "log stream" and get this error: `There was an error creating your Log Stream. Please try again.`. I have no idea what log stream name I need to create anyway.

Comment: Your Lambda function needs the AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole policy, or the equivalent, which you can see here: https://gist.github.com/gene1wood/55b358748be3c314f956 (search for AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole).

Answer (score 1):

When an AWS role is created, you must provide an **IAM Role** that will be used by the Lambda function. The permissions associated with the role will grant access to AWS services and resources required by the Lambda function.

There is a default `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` that provides:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

These permissions allow the Lambda function to write log information to Amazon CloudWatch Logs.

There are other available Roles too, such as `AWSLambdaExecute`:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        }
    ]
}
```

So, either use one of these pre-provided roles, or add similar permissions to the Role that your Lambda function is using.

Comment: Thanks John. My lambda has an execution role set to "existing role" -> "transcoder." If I visit IAM, then go to "Roles" for "transcoder", I see two policies: "AWSLambdaExecute" and "AmazonS3FullAccess" (both listed as "AWS managed policy"). The lambda execute policy does seem to indicate that this policy allows write access to the logs resource. However, now I see "This Log Group does not have any Log Streams." when I visit my log groups at "Streams for /aws/lambda/transcode-v2". Do I need to create a "log stream?" Do I need to wire my lambda to log to that stream?

Comment: If I click on the output named "Amazon CloudWatch Logs" for my lambda, it all looks like it is setup properly to me. It says it is sourcing from the managed policies listed above.

Comment: Actually, no, it is not right. I see it somehow has permissions from another lambda: `Allow: arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:798408881039:log-group:/aws/lambda/transcode-upon-upload:*`. transcode-upon-upload is another lambda I'm using.

Comment: I don't see that reference inside the "transcoder" role policies. That's strange. I'm using the amazon managed policies. I did have my own policies pasted in, but those have been deleted from the role.